# How to set Shutterspeed of Ricoh Theta S via USB using gphoto or ptpcam?

Tags: unix, android-camera, libgphoto2, theta360

I want to control a ricoh theta 360 camera using a raspberry pi 3 and ubuntu mate. I got gphoto2 via apt-get and ptp build from source. I also have the latest firmware version for the theta installed. Further, the exposure program was set to 1 (Manual program) or 4 (Shutter priority program).

to set the shutterspeed manually I tried the following:

using ptpcam:

```
   ptpcam --set-property=0xD00F --val=\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00
```

Response:

```
   Camera: RICOH THETA S
   'UNKNOWN' is set to: 
   Changing property value to x01x00x00x00x01x00x00x00 [(null)] FAILED!!!
```

using gphoto2:

```
   gphoto2 --set-config shutterspeed=0.1
```

Response:

```
   *** Error ***              
   The shutterspeed widget is not configurable.
   *** Error (-2: 'Bad parameters') ***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty useful script at github ([github: tlapser360](https://github.com/jcharcalla/tlapser360)) from Jason Charcalla.

There, it is explained that one can send a raw generic request as follows:

```
   ptpcam -R 0x1016,0xd00f,0,0,0,0,shutter.bin
```

with the shutter.bin file only containing the shutter time in hex format.

response:

```
   01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00                         - ........        
   --------------------
   Camera: RICOH THETA S
   Sending generic request: reqCode=0x1016, params=[0x0000d00f,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000]
   PTP: response OK
```

This looks pretty good. finally, one can than take an image as follows

```
   gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Jason `Charcalla script` on [github](https://github.com/theta360developers/tlapser360), with an edited `README.md` file that includes info about

1. connecting over wifi from a laptop
2. multiple flags with examples for adjusting daylight, shade, cloudy-daylight and a lot more

Example screenshots also included.